# Underscore templates failing with "unexpected identifier" in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, underscore.js

We have a Backbone / Marionette web application. The application works fine in modern browsers but dies in IE8 with

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
```

The debugger points to a line deep in the Underscore.js library rather than in my code.  Obviously there isn't a problem in the library - our code is triggering this problem.  The line is this

```
var render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out this was a specific case in one of our template which meant when the template was compiled, the code was fine in modern browsers but threw a wobbly in IE8.

We are passing data in from our view with some useful strings using the serializeData function like so (coffeescript but you get the idea):

```
...
serializeData: ->
   data = super()
   data.messages = {
      intro: "Welcome to the app"
      continue: "Click here to continue"
   }
   return data
...
```

then referencing that in the template like so

```
<h1>{{ messages.intro }}</h1>
<a href="...">{{ messages.continue }}</h1>
```

The problem comes from the fact that "continue" is a reserved word.  Coffeescript is nice and allows you to use it as a key in an object definition without quoting, and it would appear that in regular JS in more modern browsers they're ok with using it unquoted (though one would generally recommend to do so).

In IE8 however you may not set it like obj = { continue: "foo" } and you may not get it like obj.continue, it must be obj["continue"].

Replacing {{ messages.continue }} with {{ messages["continue"] }} or renaming the property fixed the issue.

Hope that helps someone :)

Rob

Comment: Same issue here. I was using `default` reserved word

Comment: Cheers! I was scratching my head for a while, then I saw this and made a 4 character change -- the whole site works again! We were using a raw object.new lookup in a template instead of object['new'].

As a sidenote, it illustrated that CommonJS modules are indeed all loaded at once, unlike AMD modules which are "loaded asynchronously as required". There doesn't seem to be a noticeable drop in performance on the mobile devices we've tested, despite the objections I've seen. However, there's a definite unforeseen benefit of having any errors caught from any page.